# How can I export data dumps into a table using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Im trying to take a data dump in a text file and sort it into a usable table using powershell. Is it possible to organize it using this or even export it to other applications like excel?

Comment: You can use all the power of .net in powershell
https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/11/04/net-members-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: `Export-Csv` comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what you are trying to export, but just as an example of exporting a heap of details from AD to a csv file. -

Get-ADUser -ResultSetSize 300 -SearchBase $OuDomain -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Csv $Filepath